# Output GCC Version Results to File

Tags: pipe, version, tee

When I run `gcc -v` I'd like to output the results to a text file.

I thought something like `gcc -v > ~/defaultGCC.txt` would store the version output but it does not.

I also tried `gcc -v | tee ~/defaultGCC.txt | more`

And that didn't work...

The following:

```
gcc -v | tee ~/defaultGCC.txt | >
gcc -v | tee ~/defaultGCC.txt | >>
```

both throw errors

Comment: Have you tried `gcc -v 2>  ~/defaultGCC.txt`?

Comment: `gcc: error: 2: No such file or directory`

Comment: No space between the `2` and the `>`?  That command should pipe stderr to the file.

Comment: Oops, just noticed that. Ah ha!! Thank YOU!! That worked. So, my guess is that 2 means the second argument? gcc would be the first, -v is the 2nd?

Comment: 2 means filehandle #2 which is stderr. 1 is stdout. 0 is stdin

Comment: Ah, yes... ok. Thanks Stephen. Much obliged!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -v` is not responsible for version infomation, but rather programs which are invoked by the compiler while `gcc --version` is responsible for displaying gcc's version to standard output. If this is what you want, then `gcc --version | tee ~/defaultGCC.txt` will work. However, if the output of `gcc -v` is what you actually want, then `gcc -v &> ~/defaultGCC.txt` will give you exactly what you want.